# Powershell variable in Azure yml file is not passed from one stage to other stages

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

Variable when output is not getting passed to other stages.
I am getting the major and minor version from .version file which is in same root folder as azure-pipelines.yml file. The first stage "GetVersion" works fine and prints the value of manor and minor but the value of major and minor is never passed to BuildMasterVersion" stage and "TagRelease" stage. Hence I see error below for BuildMasterVersion

```
The value is 
Async Command Start: Update Build Number
Update build number to ..8 for build 14074
Async Command End: Update Build Number
Finishing: PowerShell
```

And below error for TagRelease

```
major : The term 'major' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\grmn\prj\mrn\vsts-agent\_work\_temp\97b95723-b57c-451c-9e65-17cbecac17cf.ps1:3 char:20
+ if ($(git tag -l $(major).$(minor).20)) {
+                    ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (major:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
Finishing: PowerShell
```

Below is the azure-pipelines.yml

```
pool:
  name: Marine-Server

stages:

- stage: GetVersion
  displayName: Get Major and Minor Version from .Version File 
  jobs:
  - job: Get_Major_Minor_From_Version_File
    steps:
      - checkout: self
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            $version = Get-Content -Path .version -TotalCount 1
            $versionSplit = $version.Split(".")
            $major = $versionSplit[0]
            $minor = $versionSplit[1]
            Write-Host ##vso[task.setvariable variable=major;isOutput=true]$major
            Write-Host "The value of major is $($major)"
            Write-Host ##vso[task.setvariable variable=minor;isOutput=true]$minor
            Write-Host "The value of minor is $($minor)"
          name: 'GetMajorMinorVersion' 

# # Versioning master branch  builds

- stage: BuildMasterVersion
  displayName: Build_Master_Version_Number 
  #change to 'refs/head/master' or master when done  testing
  condition: and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'convert-to-commonjs-module-with-tags-implementation'), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'))
  jobs:
  - job: Build_Master_Version_Number
    # variables:
       #patch: $[counter(variables['minor'], 0)]
    variables:
      major: $[stageDependencies.GetVersion.Get_Major_Minor_From_Version_File.outputs['GetMajorMinorVersion.major']]
      minor: $[stageDependencies.GetVersion.Get_Major_Minor_From_Version_File.outputs['GetMajorMinorVersion.minor']]
      semantic: $(major).$(minor)
      buildNum: $[counter(variables['semantic'], 0)]
    steps:
      - checkout: self
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            Write-Host "The value is $(major)"
            Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(major).$(minor).$(buildNum)"
          name: 'SetMasterBuildName'      

- stage: TagRelease
  # when done testing update branch to master
  condition: and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'convert-to-commonjs-module-with-tags-implementation'), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'))
  jobs:
    - job: Tag
      variables:
        semantic: $major.$minor
        buildNum: $[counter(variables['semantic'], 0)]
      workspace:
        clean: all
      # variables:
      #   patch: $[counter(variables['minor'], 0)]
      steps:
        - checkout: self
          persistCredentials: true
        - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              if ($(git tag -l $(major).$(minor).$(buildNum))) {
                Write-Output "$(major).$(minor).$(buildNum) already released" 
              }
              else {
                git tag $(major).$(minor).$(buildNum)
                git push origin $(major).$(minor).$(buildNum)
              }
            workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
            displayName: 'Conditionally  Tag'
```

Comment: why use separate jobs for this? each job runs on a different agent and takes considerably longer to run.

Answer (score 1):

In your stage Tagrelease the variables are not available because you haven't mapped them. Which you did do in the stage before that, in buildmasterversion.

So you should copy the mapped variables major and minor from the buildmasterversion to tagrelease:

buildmasterversion:

```yaml
    variables:
      major: $[ stageDependencies.GetVersion.Get_Major_Minor_From_Version_File.outputs['GetMajorMinorVersion.major'] ]
      minor: $[ stageDependencies.GetVersion.Get_Major_Minor_From_Version_File.outputs['GetMajorMinorVersion.minor'] ]
      semantic: $(major).$(minor)
      buildNum: $[counter(variables['semantic'], 0)]
```

Tagrelease:

```yaml
      variables:
        major: $[ stageDependencies.GetVersion.Get_Major_Minor_From_Version_File.outputs['GetMajorMinorVersion.major'] ]
        minor: $[ stageDependencies.GetVersion.Get_Major_Minor_From_Version_File.outputs['GetMajorMinorVersion.minor'] ]
        semantic: $major.$minor
        buildNum: $[counter(variables['semantic'], 0)]
```

Variables that are shared between stages need to be mapped to every job that needs them, as you can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks)

Comment: I made changes as per your recommendation (i will update my code in question), but the actual problem here is major and minor is not getting passed to BuildMasterVersion. If you can check the variables in buildmasterversion is not working

Comment: Ah, I see now. I've double checked with the docs and updated my answer above to include spaces after and before the bracked. They are specifically shown in the docs and I've always used that, so that might be what's missing. Let me know if this helps.